# Serialize Python objects without file system

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, joblib

I want to serialize a trained scikit pipeline object to reload it for predictions. What I saw pickle and joblib dump are two common methods for that, whereas joblib is the preferable approach.

In my case I want to store the serialized python object in the database and load it from there, deserialize it and use it for predictions. Is it possible to serialize the object without any file system access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import joblib
from io import BytesIO
import base64
with BytesIO() as tmp_bytes:
    joblib.dump({"test": "test"}, tmp_bytes)
    bytes_obj = tmp_bytes.getvalue()
    base64_obj = base64.b64encode(bytes_obj)
```

Then, bytes_obj is a bytes object. And base64_obj is the base64 version. Select what you like.

Comment: Nice, interesting, any advantages over pickle.dumps?

Comment: joblib is faster in storing numpy arrays

Comment: Regarding python version issues it's the same as pickle?

Comment: btw: how can i load it then from the dump?

Comment: They have the same problem in different python version.

Comment: If you use bytes_obj. You should check about how to save bytes in mongo. Then load bytes from mongo and use joblib.load(BytesIO(bytes_obj)). If you use base64_obj. Then you just save base64 string in mongo. Then load base64 string from mongo. decode base64 to btyes. Then use joblib.load(BytesIO(bytes_obj)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for the pickle library you can get the serialized version of an object by using [`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) instead of `pickle.dump`.

```
serialized_object = pickle.dumps(object)
```

This returns a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object, which you should then be able to store in your database, potentially converting it to base64 before doing so, or maybe directly.

Comment: thanks, does joblib has the same problems to be not compatible when loading a dump in a different python version as pickle has?

Comment: @HansHupe don't really know that, sorry